# Perl fast CGI : do you ever exit the loop?

Tags: perl, fastcgi

Consider the standard Perl fast CGI script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI::Fast;

# Init handler

while (my $cgi = CGI::Fast->new) 
{
# Handle request
}

# Do you ever get here?
```

Do I ever exit the loop and get a chance to do some cleanup?

What happens when the server throws out the test.fpl script because the time limit has been exceeded?

Comment: If you want to do cleanup, you could do it in an `END` block I guess.

Comment: @simbabque Are you sure the END block will be executed when the server trashes the Perl interpreter instance and all its running scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure. It might. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not normally, but it is possible.

`CGI::Fast::new` is:

```
sub new {
    my ($self, $initializer, @param) = @_;

    if ( ! defined $initializer ) {
        $Ext_Request ||= _create_fcgi_request( $in_fh,$out_fh,$err_fh );
        return undef unless $Ext_Request->Accept >= 0;
    }
    CGI->_reset_globals;
    $self->_setup_symbols(@CGI::SAVED_SYMBOLS) if @CGI::SAVED_SYMBOLS;
    return $CGI::Q = $self->SUPER::new($initializer, @param);
}
```

As you can see, it can return false if `$Ext_Request->Accept` (where `$Ext_Request` is an FGCI::Request object) returns a negative number.

Drilling down gets us to a one of two C functions called `OS_Accept`, one for unix, and one for Windows. They are primarily wrappers for the `accept` system call.

`accept` primarily fail if it's interrupted by a signal or if the process runs out of resources (sockets or memory). Most other reasons would be the result of a bug in the code.

Comment: Can _create_fcgi_request fail and return undef? Is the expr $Ext_Request->Accept >= 0 false if $Ext_Request is undef?

Comment: It can throw an exception, but it can't return undef. /// No, that would be a fatal runtime error.